# Get every nth element or last

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm hitting a brick wall with this, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Given a List of objects, how can i get every third element starting from the end (so the third to last, sixth to last etc) but if it gets to the end and there are only 1 or 2 left, returns the first element.

I'm essentially trying to simulate drawing three cards from the Stock and checking for valid moves in a game of patience, but for some reason i'm struggling with this one concept.

EDIT:

So far I've tried looked into using the standard for loop increasing the step. That leads me to the second need which is to get the first element if there are less than three on the final loop.

I've tried other suggestions on stack overflow for getting nth element from a list, however they all also don't provide the second requirement.

Not entirely sure what code i could post that wouldn't be a simple for loop. as my problem is the logic for the code, not the code itself.

For example:

Given the list 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

i would like to get a list with
8, 5, 2, 1 
as the return.

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: Did you try anything? Even if it's just thought process, show us what you have so far.

Comment: I didn't expect to need code for this one, I assumed it would be pretty quick. I'll add what i've tried for this one so far tho.

Comment: @user1412240 We like to see questions that demonstrate they've put some effort into the question by doing research, jotting down pseudocode, trying things, etc.  Too many people come here expecting us to write their code for them.

Comment: Amy. I understand that fully. I'm not after someone to write code for me which is why I've not gone into depth on what exactly i need i tried to keep it generic enough to be useful to others. I also didn't want to fill my question with failed code sample and research. But trust me I've been working on this problem on and off for a few days now which leads me to asking here, feeling i'm missing that logical leap which will make this obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudocode:

```
List<object> filtered = new List<object>();
List<object> reversedList = myList.Reverse();
if(reversedList.Count % 3 != 0)
{
   return reversedList.Last();
}
else
{
   for(int i = 3; i < reversedList.Count; i = i +3)
{
   filterList.Add(reversedList[i]);
}
if(!filterList.Contains(reversedList.Last())
{
   filterList.Add(reversedList.Last());
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Guess my wording still needs a little work in my post. I'm wanting both of those to happen, So it would loop through as per your for loop, but get the first element (Since we're backwards. technically the first is last) if there isn't a third. I'll update my post a little.

Comment: so get every 3rd item AND the last item if it's not evenly divisible by 3?  If it's less than 3, only return the last?

Comment: Yes that's right. I've posted an example in my question which i hope clears it up a little

Comment: Okay, check the update.  I just reversed it so you can iterate easier.  I think this is easier to read than taking the length and subtracting 3 but if you need better performance you may have to work from the back instead of calling Reverse()

Comment: With some editing i got this to work perfect. it seems i was overthinking the whole thing and got lost in the details. I never though about doing a check AFTER the loop. which makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code -

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
int count = 1;
for (;count<=20;count++) {
    list.Add(count);
}
for (count=list.Count-3;count>=0;count-=3)
{
    Debug.Log(list[count]);
    resultList.Add(list[count]);
}
if(list.Count % 3 > 0)
{
    Debug.Log(list[0]);
    resultList.Add(list[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to try and do it with linq.
Not sure if it live up to your requirements but works with your example.

```
        var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
        //Start with reversing the order.
        var result = list.OrderByDescending(x => x)
            //Run a select overload with index so we can use position
            .Select((number, index) => new { number, index })
            //Only include items that are in the right intervals OR is the last item
            .Where(x => ((x.index + 1) % 3 == 0) || x.index == list.Count() - 1)
            //Select only the number to get rid of the index.
            .Select(x => x.number)
            .ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(8, result[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, result[1]);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result[2]);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result[3]);
```